# Why does LLVM throw an "arguments of incompatible type" error when creating an array?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-py

I am using LLVM and the llvmpy library.

My goal is to create something similar to the follow C code:

```
int a[] = {1, 2};
int b[] = {1, 2, 3};
int c[] = {1};
int* ptrs[] = {a, b, c};
```

The following is the outputted IR of the above excerpt:

```
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
%a = alloca [2 x i32], align 4
%b = alloca [3 x i32], align 4
%c = alloca [1 x i32], align 4
%ptrs = alloca [3 x i32*], align 16
store i32 0, i32* %1
%2 = bitcast [2 x i32]* %a to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %2, i8* bitcast ([2 x i32]* @main.a to i8*), i64 8, i32 4, i1 false)
%3 = bitcast [3 x i32]* %b to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %3, i8* bitcast ([3 x i32]* @main.b to i8*), i64 12, i32 4, i1 false)
%4 = bitcast [1 x i32]* %c to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %4, i8* bitcast ([1 x i32]* @main.c to i8*), i64 4, i32 4, i1 false)
%5 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32*]* %ptrs, i64 0, i64 0
%6 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i32]* %a, i32 0, i32 0
store i32* %6, i32** %5
%7 = getelementptr inbounds i32** %5, i64 1
%8 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32]* %b, i32 0, i32 0
store i32* %8, i32** %7
%9 = getelementptr inbounds i32** %7, i64 1
%10 = getelementptr inbounds [1 x i32]* %c, i32 0, i32 0
store i32* %10, i32** %9
%11 = load i32* %1
ret i32 %11
```

I believe I have understood this well enough - it simply grabs the pointers to the head of each individual array, and then uses `getelementptr` to walk along the storage array and insert each pointer.

Here is what I came up with in `llvmpy`:

```
pointers = []
for array in arrays:
    # Store each of the { 1, ... } arrays in memory.
    type = Type.array(Type.int(), len(arrays))
    ptr = builder.alloca_array(type, Constant.int(Type.int(), len(arrays)))
    builder.store(array, ptr)
    # And keep track of their pointers.
    indices = [ Constant.int(Type.int(), 0), Constant.int(Type.int(), 0) ]
    head = builder.gep(ptr, indices)
    pointers.append(head)
# Finally, construct the array to hold the pointers.
type = Type.pointer(Type.int())
array = Constant.array(type, pointers)
return array
```

But I receive the error:

> include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:219: typename cast_retty::ret_type llvm::cast_or_null(llvm::Value *): Assertion
>   `isa(Val) && "cast_or_null() argument of incompatible type!"'
>   failed.

on the line containing the code:

```
array = Constant.array(type, pointers)
```

When I check the type of the pointers and the type of the array, they both seem to be `int32*`. What am I doing wrong? And, is `Value` a generic placeholder that needs to be cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the equivalent of writing the following, *illegal*, IR:

```
%x = getelementptr ...
%y = getelementptr ...
%z = getelementptr ...
%array = [ i32* %x, i32* %y, i32* %z ]
```

Why illegal? Because you are trying to create a **constant** array (you're using the `Constant` class - so `Constant.array` is equivalent to using the `[]` array literal syntax above) that holds **non-constant** values (`%x`, `%y` and `%z`). If you want to store these pointers in an array, you have to `alloca` the array first, then `store` each pointer in turn inside it.

Comment: Thanks, between this and your other answer I think I understand how it works a bit better.